# Can you return old RAID 1 disks(and keep all the files on them) to Windows Server machine if migrating to new disks fails?

Tags: windows, raid, restore, migration

I'm looking for some help regarding RAID 1 and migration to bigger disks.

Here is the thing. I have to migrate Dell PowerEdge T30 disks that are in RAID 1 to new and bigger disks. From what I understand the process should be fairly easy. I've done it as a test already, but I don't wanna mess with my company's files anymore xD

So, to migrate the server my plan is:

1. Create a full backup of the system (it is running Windows Server 2016 Essentials)
2. Shut down the server and take old drives out.
3. Install new(bigger) drives
4. Start server and create new RAID 1 array
5. Boot server with Windows Server 2016 installation disc, and when it boots click on "Repair System"
6. Go to "Restore" and restore the server from the external drive

My first test with this went well, but I was wondering what I can do if Server Restore fails?
Can I just insert old drives and will the server work like it did before? Do I have to create another raid or something? Is it even possible to make it work after new RAID 1(for new drivers) is created?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Does the T30 allow removing disks while the server is still running?